# How to pass arguments to a docker container without specifying a CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Currently if I run a container I *must* speicfy a new `CMD` in order to pass args.

I.e. the format is `docker run image [CMD] [ARGS]`

Is there any way to pass args to the `CMD` at the end of the `Dockerfile` without specifying a new `CMD` when running the container.

Comment: You can just pass CMD [args] in the end of your dockerfile. CMD is also an instruction in Dockerfile. It would be better if you have an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this probably works for you is that usually, the default ENTRYPOINT is `/bin/bash -c`, and then when you add CMD with executable it adds to the ENTRYPOINT to run the CMD contents as you'd expect.

> CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)

> CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

[Dockerfile docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

This means your main option is to replace the old CMD with an ENTRYPOINT in the new Dockerfile and append the runtime arguments with a new CMD directive, either with permanent default values, ones received from environment variables, or a combination of the two

Hopes this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can write your CMD statement like this at end of the Dockerfile.

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
```

source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/